# WooCommerce call ajax refresh with jquery on every 30 seconds in the orders page

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, partial-page-refresh

This is my function to call ajax partial page refresh with jquery on every 30 seconds:

```
setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({url: "url.txt", success: function(result){
        $("#containerDiv").html(result);
        }}}, 30000);
```

But I can't find the right file to place it. Where is exactly the *.php file that contains the table with the woocommerce orders in admin panel located?

Comment: I don't think that this is going to really work as you are expecting, but anyway you can try [one of the hooks of this answer related to backend orders list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36446617/woocommerce-add-custom-columns-to-admin-orders-list-page/36453587) … If you got a working solution, please answer to your question, and notify me. I will upvote your answer.

Comment: But these hooks are for the table columns. If possible can you provide one specific for the whole orders table ?

Comment: Search in here (in Amin Hooks section): https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html or try to look into the core source code for WC orders list, if there is any hook that you can use.