# WooCommerce - orders at a glance on admin side - add a column to display the SKU # within the order and 1 specific attribute within the order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, orders, sku

I really hope someone can help me. When we access our "Orders" page on the admin side, we need to be able to see the orders **SKU** & a **specific product attribute** at a glance.

Can anyone assist me with this? I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thank you in advance.

Jane

Comment: May be duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36446617/woocommerce-add-custom-columns-to-admin-orders-list-page/36453587

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use variation products you can simply turn on the SKU from the Screen Options at the top of the page

I've used a plugin called [WooCommerce Bulk Stock Management](https://woocommerce.com/products/bulk-stock-management/) it costs $ 49 but beats coding a custom view from zero for viewing and editing stock levels of all the product variations (one of the requirements for my needs was to be able to see the SKU numbers of all variations at once since the WooCommerce product view groups variations)

Comment: Hello,Thanks for your reply. But unfortunately when I go into:

Admin > WooCommerce > Orders Screen Options

There is not option for "SKU" and no we don't use product variations.

I will look into this plugin.

Thanks!

Jane