# Display 'tax status' on WooCommerce admin product list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, admin

How can I go about displaying the product 'tax status' (ie. taxable, delivery only, none) on the product list of the admin page?

I've been trying to display products as 'In Stock/Out of Stock' and 'Taxable/Not Taxable' on the product list so that I can easily determine the status of products and make changes if necessary.

I figured out how to display the Stock Status on the product list, however, when I try the same with the 'tax status', it doesn't work. I got Stock Status to display by adding the following code to functions.php. How can I have the 'Tax Status' display?

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_columns', 'product_column_arrange' );
function product_column_arrange( $product_columns ) {

    return array(
             ...
             'is_in_stock' => 'Stock',
             ...
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will display a custom column for product tax status in admin product list:

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_columns', 'tax_status_product_column');
function tax_status_product_column($columns){
    $new_columns = [];
    foreach( $columns as $key => $column ){
        $new_columns[$key] = $columns[$key];
        if( $key == 'is_in_stock' ) {
            $new_columns['tax_status'] = __( 'Tax status','woocommerce');
        }
    }
    return $new_columns;
}

add_action( 'manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'tax_status_product_column_content', 10, 2 );
function tax_status_product_column_content( $column, $post_id ){
    if( $column == 'tax_status' ){
        global $post, $product;

        // Excluding variable and grouped products
        if( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
            $args =  array(
                'taxable'  => __( 'Taxable', 'woocommerce' ),
                'shipping' => __( 'Shipping only', 'woocommerce' ),
                'none'     => _x( 'None', 'Tax status', 'woocommerce' ),
            );

            echo $args[$product->get_tax_status()];
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Related: [Add custom columns to admin products list in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45693818/add-custom-columns-to-admin-products-list-in-woocommerce-3/45695499#45695499)