# Add custom URL link to admin order list page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, hook-woocommerce

Hi I am trying to add an AfterShip tracking button or link to my Admin Order list in the backend. I have succesfully created a new column that displays the tracking number for each order. However, I would like to make the tracking number clickable. Or, as an alternative, create an action button that opens a new tab and tracks the number in the Tracking Number column.

The URL format I need is as follows:
https://track.aftership.com/LS325245095CN?

Notice that there is a question mark appended to the tracking number. I would need to do this with the action, since the question mark symbol is not used when entering the tracking number.

Here is the code I am using for displaying the tracking number column in the admin orders list in the backend:

```
//Start Add Tracking Number to Admin Orders List
//Start Add Header to List
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'custom_shop_order_column', 
12, 1 );
function custom_shop_order_column($columns)
{
// Set "Actions" column after the new colum
$action_column = $columns['order_actions']; // Set the title in a variable
unset($columns['order_actions']); // remove  "Actions" column


//add the new column "New Tracking Number"
$columns['order_astracking'] = '<span>'.__( 'Tracking Number','woocommerce').'</span>'; // title

// Set back "Actions" column
$columns['order_actions'] = $action_column;

return $columns;
}

//END Add Header to List
//START Add Tracking Number Data to List
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 
'custom_order_list_column_content', 10, 2 );
function custom_order_list_column_content( $column, $post_id )
{

// HERE get the data from your custom field (set the correct meta key below)
$astracking = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_aftership_tracking_number', true );
if( empty($astracking)) $astracking = '';

switch ( $column )
{
    case 'order_astracking' :
        echo '<span>'.$astracking.'</span>'; // display the data
        break;
}
}
//END Add Tracking Number Data to List

//START Make Tracking Number Data Searchable in Admin Orders List
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_fields', 
'astracking_search_fields', 10, 1 );
function astracking_search_fields( $meta_keys ){
$meta_keys[] = '_aftership_tracking_number';
return $meta_keys;
}
//END Make Tracking Number Data Searchable in Admin Orders List

//END Add Tracking Number to Admin Orders List
```

I got this code here on Stackoverflow.. awesome resource.

[Add custom columns to admin orders list in WooCommerce backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36446617/add-custom-columns-to-admin-orders-list-in-woocommerce-backend?rq=1)

Any help or suggestions you could provide, would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you Update woocommerce to version 3.3+ I have added a link to a new functional version of this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **New Update for WC 3.3+:** [Custom action button in admin orders list on Woocommerce 3.3+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48959047/custom-action-button-in-admin-orders-list-on-woocommerce-3-3/48959768#48959768)

Here is the way to add an action button in admin order list with a custom link related to tracking *(opening the link in a **new window** as requested)*:

```
// Add your custom order action button
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions_end', 'add_custom_order_actions_button', 100, 1 );
function add_custom_order_actions_button( $order ) {

    // Get the tracking number
    $traking_number = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_aftership_tracking_number', true );
    if( empty($traking_number) ) return;

    // Prepare the button data
    $url    = esc_url('https://track.aftership.com/'.$traking_number.'?');
    $name   = esc_attr( __('Tracking', 'woocommerce' ) );
    $action = esc_attr( 'view tracking' ); // keep "view" class for a clean button CSS

    // Set the action button
    printf( '<a class="button tips %s" href="%s" data-tip="%s" target="_blank">%s</a>', $action, $url, $name, $name );
}

// The icon of your action button (CSS)
add_action( 'admin_head', 'add_custom_order_actions_button_css' );
function add_custom_order_actions_button_css() {
    echo '<style>.view.tracking::after { font-family: woocommerce; content: "\e005" !important; }</style>';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works. You will get something like:

[image]

---

Now To make your tracking number clickable you will replace this function in your code:

```
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'custom_order_list_column_content', 10, 2 );
function custom_order_list_column_content( $column, $post_id )
{

    // HERE get the data from your custom field (set the correct meta key below)
    $astracking = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_aftership_tracking_number', true );
    if( empty($astracking)) $astracking = '';

    switch ( $column )
    {
        case 'order_astracking' :
            echo '<span><a href="https://track.aftership.com/'.$astracking.'?" target="_blank">'.$astracking . '</a></span>'; // display the data
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is so awesome. Works great! Thank you so much. Just one quick question, though. If I wanted to force the button to open the page in a new tab or window, how would I need to edit the URL. Thanks again.

Comment: That is just too awesome! Works like a charm. I guess can just "wheel-click" the link or button for now.. Hopefully, can figure out to open in new tab or window. But, this already much easier and better than I had imagined.. Thanks again.

Comment: @JessDaddy I just found the way to get the button link open in a new window… I have updated my answer code. Thanks

Comment: You, my friend, are a true guru and savior. I bow in the presence of your greatness! Awesome. Perfect.