# Add a custom column to the admin Email notifications list in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, backend, email-notifications

How can I add a custom column to the Email notifications listing page in the WooCommerce admin area?

I found [a similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36446617/add-columns-to-admin-orders-list-in-woocommerce), but on adding a custom column to the Order list. I wonder if I can do the same for Email notifications.