# Custom columns in WooCommerce admin orders list doesn't display data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

I need help to display custom order metadata in WooCommerce orders list. I have added a new custom column called "Meeting Points" and "Meeting Date&Time."

[image]

Here is my code so far:

```php
add_filter('manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'add_meeting_points_column');
function add_meeting_points_column($columns) {
    $columns = array_merge(
        array_slice($columns, 0, array_search('order_date', array_keys($columns)), true),
        array('meeting_points' => __('Meeting Points', 'text-domain')),
        array_slice($columns, array_search('order_date', array_keys($columns)), null, true)
    );
    return $columns;
}

add_action('manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'display_meeting_points_column', 20, 2);
function display_Meeting_Points_column($column, $post_id) {
    if ('Meeting_Points' === $column) {
        $order = wc_get_order($post_id);

        if ($order) {
            $meeting_points = wc_get_order_meta_keys($order->get_keys(), 'MeetingPoints', true);
            echo !empty($meeting_points) ? esc_html($meeting_points) : esc_html__('Not Available', 'text-domain');
        }
    }
}
```

My code doesn't work as expected, it doesn't display the data.

[image]

What I am doing wrong? Your assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple mistakes in your 2nd function, for example column string value should be`'meeting_points'` instead of `'Meeting_Points'`, to populate the column with your custom metadata.

Try the following code replacement *(making sure that `MeetingPoints` and `MeetingDate&Time` are the correct meta keys used in `wp_postmeta` database table for your orders)*:

```php
add_filter('manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'add_meeting_points_column');
function add_meeting_points_column($columns) {
    $columns = array_merge(
        array_slice($columns, 0, array_search('order_date', array_keys($columns)), true),
        array(
            'meeting_points'   => __('Meeting Points', 'text-domain'),
            'meeting_datetime' => __('Meeting DateTime', 'text-domain'),
        ),
        array_slice($columns, array_search('order_date', array_keys($columns)), null, true)
    );
    return $columns;
}

add_action('manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'display_meeting_points_column', 20, 2);
function display_Meeting_Points_column($column, $post_id) {
    global $the_order;

    if ($column === 'meeting_points') {
        echo ($value = $the_order->get_meta('MeetingPoints')) ? esc_html($value) : esc_html__('Not Available', 'text-domain');
    } elseif ($column === 'meeting_datetime') {
        echo ($value = $the_order->get_meta('MeetingDate&Time')) ? esc_html($value) : esc_html__('Not Available', 'text-domain');
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

In admin orders list:

[image]

In database under `wp_postmeta` table (example):

[image]

---

##### Addition:

###### Helper function to get the correct extra meta keys *(temporary)*

The following hooked function will display in any Admin Order Edit Page, all the extra meta keys from the order and from the order items:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'admin_order_display_extra_meta_keys');
function admin_order_display_extra_meta_keys( $order ) {
    $meta_keys = [];
    foreach($order->get_meta_data() as $meta_data) {
        $meta_keys[] = $meta_data->get_data()['key']; 
    }
    if ( ! empty($meta_keys) ) {
        echo '<p><strong>1) Order Meta keys:</strong><br>';
        echo '<code>'. print_r( implode('</code><br><code>',$meta_keys), true ) . '</code></p>';
    }

    $meta_keys = [];
    foreach($order->get_items() as $item) {
        foreach($item->get_meta_data() as $meta_data) {
            $meta_keys[] = $meta_data->get_data()['key']; 
        }
    }
    if ( ! empty($meta_keys) ) {
        echo '<p><strong>2) Order items Meta keys:</strong><br>';
        echo '<code>'. print_r( implode('</code><br><code>',$meta_keys), true ) . '</code></p>';
    }
}
```

Temporary code that goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).

[image]

Related:

- [Add columns to admin orders list in WooCommerce (+ HPOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36446617/add-columns-to-admin-orders-list-in-woocommerce-hpos/36453587#36453587)
- [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)

Comment: thanks for the answer.
i put the replacement code.but i dont know why, it's show me "Not Available"
here the screen shoot.
http://travelintrips.co.id/wp-content/uploads/2024/01/Screenshot_35.png

Comment: @QnZFamily You need to check in `wp_postmeta` database table that `MeetingPoints` and `MeetingDate&Time` are the correct `meta_key`… If not, replace them with the correct ones…

Answer (score -1):

It will help to get the right meta key values.   You can add this code to functions.php and then visit an order page in the Dashboard to see a list of all the meta keys for each product in the order in the output in the footer.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_display_admin_footer_text', 'chad_woocommerce_show_order_meta_on_order_page');
function chad_woocommerce_show_order_meta_on_order_page() { 
    $order = new WC_Order( get_the_ID() );
    if( $order ){
        foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ){
            $product_id = $item['product_id'];
            $custom_fields = get_post_custom($product_id);
            foreach( $custom_fields as $key => $value){
                echo '<br>'.$key;
            }
            echo '<br><br>';
        }
    }
}
```