# Custom Column in WooCommerce Admin Order list based on order item metadata

Tags: php, woocommerce, orders

Trying to add a custom column to the WooCommerce list of orders in the backend order admin. page; column is inserted but can't seem to get the value from the database. I'm trying to retrieve a value in the wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta table. I've verified the correct meta key but can't seem to grab the value correctly.

This value is a "shipping speed" choice made by the customer when they place their order (not the standard Woo shipping methods, this is a place where the customer says either "ship my order when everything's complete" or "ship piecemeal as things are ready").

Don't ask how many hours I've burned on this--you don't want to know. Maybe a fresh set of eyes would help.

```
//add a custom column to the Woo Commerce orders list for "shipping speed"

//create a new column labelled "Shipping Speed
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'add_new_order_admin_list_column' );
function add_new_order_admin_list_column( $columns ) {
    $columns['shipping_speed'] = 'Shipping Speed';
    return $columns;
}

//populate the column with the correct values for each order
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'add_new_order_admin_list_column_content' );
function add_new_order_admin_list_column_content( $column ) {
    global $post;
    if ( 'shipping_speed' === $column ) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $post->ID );
        $item = $order->get_items();
        //get the custom field value from the wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta table
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
            $custom_field = wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_wc_checkout_add_on_value', true ); 
        }
        //Does the custom field value contain the word 'grinding'?
        if ( str_contains( $custom_field, 'grinding' ) ) {
            echo "Get Me Grinding";
        }
        else echo 'no rush';
    }
}
```

Comment: In what table did you checked for `_wc_checkout_add_on_label` meta key? If you have High-Performance Order Storage *(HPOS)* enabled, use instead [Add columns to admin orders list in WooCommerce (+ HPOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36453587/3730754).

Comment: @LoicTheAztec thanks for responding, this is from the wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta table. I revised my code to use wc_get_order_item_meta but it still seems like I'm not getting the value correctly--seems to return empty no matter what. But when I look in the database table I can see the value there that I want to grab. What am I missing here? Thanks a million.

Comment: Inside your 2nd function, try to replace your current code with: `if ( 'shipping_speed' === $column ) {
        global $the_order;
        $contains_grinding = false;
        foreach( $the_order->get_items(['line_item', 'shipping', 'fee']) as $item ){
      $meta_value = strval( $item->get_meta('_wc_checkout_add_on_value') );
            if ( str_contains( $meta_value, 'grinding' ) ) {
                $contains_grinding = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        echo $contains_grinding ? __("Get Me Grinding") : __("no rush");
    }`

Comment: Merci mon ami! Your function works like a charm. I made a few changes to refine my use case but task is now complete! Appreciate your time.

Comment: The provided answer in the duplicate, with modifications to column names and meta keys, can guide adding a "shipping speed" column. By replacing "Meeting Points" with "shipping speed" details and adjusting data retrieval to match the correct meta key, the process outlined—adding and populating a custom column—remains applicable, enabling its use for this question.